# Match up 2 columns in excel from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I'm having trouble comparing two worksheets.  I have worksheet A and worksheet B.  In each worksheet, column A have the customer number and column B have the date.  The same client and same date can occur in different rows but there is a third value that will differentiate the difference (column C) for the price they paid for their items. Is there a formula or function which allows comparing two columns with another two columns in a different sheet?

Comment: Did you ask a question? o.o

Comment: Please show us a sample worksheet together with the desired result

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, i like to use VBA one very basic example is :

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim result As Long, result2 As Long
Dim duplicated As Boolean
Dim fstrst As Long, lstrst As Long

Set Sheet1 = Workbook1  ' add your workbook here like this
Set sheet2 = Workbook2  ' Workbooks("testbook").Sheets("sheet1")

' this says count the values from row 1 to the end of the data
fstrst = 1
lstrst = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For result = fstrst To lstrst
    duplicated = False
For result2 = fstrst To lstrst

If Sheet1.Cells(result, 3) = sheet2.Cells(result2, 3) Then
    duplicated = True
    Exit For
     End If

Next result2
If duplicated = True Then
 ' if there are any matching values then duplicated will appear in column C
 Sheet1.Cells(result, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = duplicated

 End If

Next result

End Sub
```

This will compare mulitple workbooks and return a value based on any duplications, but it can be changed to compare more columns, return different values or delete the duplication etc

A Worksheet based example could be using a vlookup with an embedded if formula to check certain criteria for example =IF(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!A:B,1,0),"Duplicated"," ") this would tell you if anything has been duplicated and if not nothing is shown. But it all depends on what you want to see.

Hope it helps

Tom